# how to make apache run pyc file (python compiled file)

Tags: python, apache

I am using apache2 and python2.6 on linux.

I know how to make apache run a *.py file, just add "AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py" to httpd.conf file. But how to make apache2 run a *.pyc file?

Adding "AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pyc" is not working.

I've heard that mod_python can enable both *.pyc and *.pyo run on apache. Could anybody tell me how does mod_python make it?

By the way in the current I don't want to learn mod_python or WSGI...

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't use CGI for your Python scripts at all. WSGI is the way to go.

Comment: Seriously, if you're even semi-proficient with Python, there's virtually nothing to "learn" to use WSGI.  You can grab the simplest example code, insert your existing code into a few handlers, and away you go.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But I insist using CGI right now as I'm  a beginner, it's simple, powerfull and pythonic! I would rather develope something like fastcgi or wsgi in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that httpd doesn't know how to run a .pyc file, since unlike a .py file (with its shebang line), a .pyc file contains no information on how it should be run. You will need to use [binfmt_misc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc) to instruct Linux on how to run a .pyc file. And don't forget to make the file itself executable as well.

Answer (score 1):

It should work. If it doesn't, try running the .pyc file in question from the command line. If that does not work either, [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/73615/how-do-pyc-files-execute) might help.

Apart from that, I'm wondering what the reason is for not using the python source files?

Comment: Thank you for your advice! My python scripts are OK! But I want to run it on web via apache (as cgi script).And I think compiled file runs faster and protects the source code to some extent.

Comment: The Python interpreter will look for a compiled version of a .py file you're running before compiling it, so there's no real advantage here.

Answer (score 0):

In apache config file you add lines in section virtualhost:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/bin/
Action cgi-handler /cgi-bin/python3
AddHandler cgi-handler .py .pyc .pyo

<Directory /usr/bin>
  Require all granted
  Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

This complete example of configuration file to www.domain.com.br.conf (in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/)

```
DocumentRoot /home/domain.com.br/www/
ServerName domain.com.br
ServerAlias www.domain.com.br

<Directory /home/domain.com.br/www/>
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/bin/
Action cgi-handler /cgi-bin/python3
AddHandler cgi-handler .py .pyc .pyo

<Directory /usr/bin>
  Require all granted
  Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```