# How to run .pyc file with apache?

Tags: apache, python-2.7

Is there any way to run .pyc file instead of .py with apache ?. I am running a project using apache but apache interprets .py file but i want to run .pyc file in apache.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make apache run pyc file (python compiled file)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603893/how-to-make-apache-run-pyc-file-python-compiled-file)

Comment: @shadow0359 - thanks for the reply, i am running the python through WSGI module in apache,i am not using CGI so can you guide me how to run the .pyc file through WSGI in apache